# My code containing if block and replace function working more than I expect but I do not know why

Tags: python, if-statement, replace, while-loop

I'm writing a manual currency conversion program and this is my code:

```
import math


def converter():
    while True:
        def convert():
            hint = '1-eur 2-gbp 3-nzd 4-aud 5-pln 6-aed 7-zar 8-cad 9-chf 10-dkk 11-inr 12-brl 13-hkd 14-pen 15-czk' \
                   ' 16-jpy 17-nok 18-sek 19-qar 20-cny'
            currency_hint = ['EUR', 'GBP', 'NZD', 'AUD', 'PLN', 'AED', 'ZAR', 'CAD', 'CHF', 'DKK', 'INR', 'BRL', 'HKD',
                             'PEN', 'CZK', 'JPY', 'NOK', 'SEK', 'QAR', 'CNY']
            currency_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
            domain_extension = input('Enter domain extension: ')
            if domain_extension[0] == '.':
                domain_extension = domain_extension.replace(domain_extension[0], '')
                print(domain_extension)
            '''if domain_extension[-1] == '.':
                domain_extension = domain_extension.replace(domain_extension[-1], '')'''
            currency = int(input(f'What is the currency? {hint}: '))

            try:
                if currency == currency_list[0]:
                    amount = float(input('How much? ')) * 1.17  # euro
                    return f'You chose extension .{domain_extension} with currency {currency_hint[0]} and it is ' \
                           f'{math.ceil(amount)} USD.'
            except IndexError:
                return 'Try Again'
        me = convert()
        print(me)
        break


converter()
```

**What I'm getting now is:** I enter my extension like `....com....` and I choose number 1 which is `EUR` and I set the amount to `1` for example. In this case I expected to return value like `You chose extension .com.... with currency EUR and it is 2 USD.`, but if fact I'm getting `You chose extension .com with currency EUR and it is 2 USD.` and I really do not know why.

My assumption is:

> My `while` loop iterates over `domain_extension` variable and its 1st position to remove `.` character from the beginning until it has no other `.` characters, and then goes to the `try...except` block.

**What I did not get is why `.` at the end are removed?** I did not write any codes to replace them with anything. At first I thought `if domain_extension[-1] == '.'` block was doing that, but when I comment this part, it's still removing `.` from the end.

And if I comment `if domain_extension[0] == '.'` block, I get domain name like `.....com....`.

**The question is why am I getting this result?** Would you please help me regarding this?

I should note that I am **happy** I'm getting this result, but because I wrote this code I do not understand why and how it is working and it made me thinking a lot but I got no clear answer yet.

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect to happen when you do `domain_extension = domain_extension.replace(domain_extension[0], '')`, even one time? And why? Now, read the documentation. Does it still make sense?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `domain_extension.lstrip('.')`?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.
Your posted code hangs, waiting for input.  Hard-code your test data; don't expect us to develop or enter it for you.  Why do you define a function inside a loop?

Comment: Why am I getting negative points? @KarlKnechtel the code you wrote is working fine, but why is it removing the dots from the end? This is what I do not get.

Comment: @Saeed because `str.replace()` does the replacement over the _whole_ string, not just the front of it.

Comment: I didn't write any code. I copied a line from your code. I downvoted you because your question is answered by the documentation, and as someone who's been using Stack Overflow for several years and who has a gold badge, you should know how to check the documentation. It removes the dots from the end because it that is part of what it's designed to do - like it says, in the documentation.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy but I wrote that only zero index should be removed. I told Python if first character is dot, replace it with '' and remove it in fact, but I did not tell him about -1 or the last index. Am I wrong?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you my friends. I got my answers now completely.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy thank you my friends. I got my answers now completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should thank [KarlKnechtel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel) and [GreenCloakGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648811/green-cloak-guy) for helping me, referring me to the Documentation and hinting me.

What my code is doing and the answer is:

**If the first index is `.`, then finds over the whole string and remove them all.**

So this is how it works and I did not know why, that I read the docs to understand and also these two friends helped me.